# Angular JS/Dojo widget parsing

Tags: javascript, dojo, angularjs

I have an Angular JS application, in which I would like (actually I MUST) use dojo widgets. In the HTML template for the controller, I can return HTML that has dojo markup in it. However, the dojo parsing doesn't happen automatically when a view gets re-rendered. The only way I have been able to trigger reparsing is by manually calling the parser after a slight delay by doing something like this in the controller and then calling it when I know the model has changed.

```
refreshDojo = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        require(["dojo/parser"], function(parser) {
                parser.parse()
                });
        }, 10);
}
```

This isn't really feasible for two reasons:

1. Having to do anything after a timeout is bound to cause trouble by
   either happening to quickly before the html has been processed or
   two slowly, causing a flash of content before the widgets are
   created.
2. Secondly, if I am not mistaken, parser.parse() parses the whole DOM
   which is not very efficient if I only updated a single div.

Is there a way to know for certain when the DOM has stabilized so that I can be sure to trigger this at the right time? And is there a way to access the root element of the controller (It appears that you can no longer inject $element)?

Answer (score 3):

You should decorate the `$compile` service, so before angular compiles anything it will let dojo compile it.

Here's a small example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9iJJFLWDqGtyqLV5Mbe3?p=preview

Documentation on decorators: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide#decorator](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#decorator)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an attribute directive `dojoType` that requires the named widget module (and mixins if needed) and instantiates them instead of the dojo parser.

For example, if you've loaded a part of the DOM ('ajax'), then you would first create a new scope for it, compile and link it against the scope (the dojoType directive gets applied), then you would call the dojo parser and specify the `rootNode`.

```
dojoParser.parse({
    rootNode: dom.byId(domid)
}).then(/* access the widgets or whatever */);
```